# Quad-port ram from single or double port ram?

Tags: memory, vhdl, verilog, system-verilog

In a design I am currently working on, I need quad port ram. However implementing it in lookup tables is using a massive amount of area and I cant reach the needed performance with that setup. Since, my FPGA has hardware blocks for single and dual port ram, is there anyway I can combine them to make quad port memory?

Comment: Why are people voting to close this?

Comment: I didn't vote-to-close, but people are voting this as off-topic, probably because this is pretty tenuous as a programming question.  You'd probably get much better answers at e.g. http://electronics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yeah, I debated about where this belongs for a while, Its seems to be a bit of a gray area once you start talking about HDLs. I ended up choosing to post it on stackoverflow because it appeared to have more previous questions dealing with HDLs, and has a much larger userbase.

Comment: I think the problem is that your question doesn't have much to do with HDLs, it has to do with the specifics of using FPGA resources.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth True, what would be the best way to move it?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I think admins have the ability to migrate a question, but I don't know how to get their attention!

Answer (score 4):

You could consider double-clocking the block RAM, although this will have implications for timing, etc.

See e.g. http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp228.pdf.

If you only need quad read access, then you just need two dual-port block RAMs, both connected to the same write-enable and write data.

Comment: I did look into double clocking, however I wanted to see if there was other techniques that didn't result in as large of a performance hit. Funnily enough I was already planning on using the other trick you mentioned as I actually need to perform 4 writes and 8 reads each clock.